# Stop form dropdown list from refreshing and losing index

Tags: xhtml

I have a form, that includes a drop down list, and a submit button.

The drop down list has 5 values.

Let's say the user chooses value #3, then clicks submit.  How would I prevent the drop down list from setting itself back to value #1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your Submit your side should know what was submitted.
You can tell your DropDownList what was seleced befor by setting the seleced Value as selected.

Example:

```
<select name='myselect'>
<option value='1' <?php if($myselect == '1') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>#1</option>
<option value='2' <?php if($myselect == '2') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>#2</option>
<option value='3' <?php if($myselect == '3') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>#3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

use your serverside script to set `selected="selected"` for the selected `<option>`.

Comment: use you script to set selected for the last selected option... i don't understand whats the problem.